# How do you rename a workspace

Tags: interface, workspaces

I duplicated my "Layout" workspace and it created a workspace called "Layout.001".  I would like to rename this to "Default", but I don't see how to do this.  I tried right-clicking on the name and I get several options, none of which is "rename".  Any suggestions?

[image: screenshot of right-click menu on workspace tab]

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out.  Double-click on the workspace name to rename it.

[image: what you see when you double-click on workspace name]